# curl_multi_getcontent における CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER オプション設定について

Tags: php, xml, php-curl

Q1.curlのハンドルとは何ですか？
オブジェクトのようなものですか？

Q2.curl_multi_getcontentでCURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER オプション設定していない場合は、何が返りますか？

Q3.curl_multi_getcontentでCURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER オプション設定している場合に返る文字列形式のハンドル内容とは何ですか？

Q4.例えば、RSSを取得した場合、その後のパース操作選択肢としては何がありますか？
・文字列形式なので文字列としてパース操作？
・ハンドルなので、オブジェクトとしてXMLをパース操作？

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER に何らかのハンドルが設定されている場合に、 この関数はその cURL
> ハンドルの内容を文字列形式で返します。

[curl_multi_getcontent](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.curl-multi-getcontent.php)

環境
PHP7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[質問する前に公式マニュアルをみましょう](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.curl-multi-getcontent.php)

Q.1 ハンドルとは、CurlHandle クラスのオブジェクトです
Q.2 nullが返るとマニュアルに記載されています。
Q.3 送信先の返してきた内容文です。
Q.4 XMLが文字列として返るのでSimpleXMLなどでパース処理が必要です。